# Python - NameError al llamar una funcion con string

Tags: python-3.x, funciones

```
def Leap_year(year):

    if((year % 400 == 0) or  #Corroboro el calculo
       (year % 100 != 0) and  
       (year % 4 == 0)):
       return "Es año bisiesto"
    return "No es año bisiesto"


Leap_year(2012) #aqui funciona porque es numerico
Leap_year(dosmildoce) #aqui no funciona y me sale NameError, el nombre "" no esta definido.
```

Ya intente con:

```
while year.isnumeric():#esto antes del if
else: print("ingrese el año en numeros") #esto despues del ultimo return
```

Comment: Buen día y ¿Cuál es el problema o qué es lo que esperarías que sucediera? Por cierto `dosmildoce` no es `string`, hacen falta ya sea comillas dobles `"` o simples `'`, por eso te sale ese error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El patrón usual a seguir cuando debes ingresar valores numéricos es:

```
try:
    valor = int(input("Ingrese valor: "))
    # Aqui haces tu proceso con el valor numerico validado
except ValueError:
    # El usuario ingresó algo no numérico.
    print("Error en el ingreso")
```

Si las instrucciones dentro del bloque `try` producen una condición de excepción, se aborta la ejecución del resto y el control salta al `except` declarado para esa excepción en particular.

En este caso, si intentas aplicar `int()` a un string, se produce la excepción `ValueError`, lo que me dice que el ingreso no es válido.

Aplicado al código OP:

```
try:
    year = int(input("Ingrese el año: "))
    print(Leap_year(year))
except ValueError:
    print("Año debe ser numérico: ")
```

lo que puedes encerrar en un ciclo para ir probando con diversos valores.

#### Demo

```
def Leap_year(year):

    if((year % 400 == 0) or  #Corroboro el calculo
       (year % 100 != 0) and  
       (year % 4 == 0)):
       return "Es año bisiesto"
    return "No es año bisiesto"


while True:
    try:
        year = int(input("Ingrese el año: "))
        print(Leap_year(year))
    except ValueError:
        print("Año debe ser numérico: ")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese el año: 2021
No es año bisiesto
Ingrese el año: dosmilveinte
Año debe ser numérico: 
Ingrese el año:
```

Comment: Hola Candid. Buen dia. Muchas gracias. Se que con try y except podia solucionarlo pero no podia encontrarle la vuelta sin eso. Necesitaba solucionarlo de forma mas simple y no podia. De verdad muchas gracias por tu respuesta y ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Otra opción es evaluar si el valor ingresado en el argumento `year` es un entero, para eso utilizamos `isinstance()`

```
def Leap_year(year):
    if isinstance(year, int):
        if((year % 400 == 0) or  #Corroboro el calculo
           (year % 100 != 0) and  
           (year % 4 == 0)):
            return "Es año bisiesto"
        return "No es año bisiesto"
    else:
        return 'El valor ingresado no es numérico'


print(Leap_year(2012))
print(Leap_year('dosmildoce'))
print(Leap_year(-2012))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Es año bisiesto
El valor ingresado no es numérico
Es año bisiesto
```

**Edición:** Únicamente debes tener en cuenta que el módulo y división para números negativos funciona un poco diferente, por lo que tal vez no resulte con números negativos. [Lectura recomendada.](https://es.acervolima.com/como-realizar-el-modulo-con-valores-negativos-en-python/)

Comment: Hola buen dia!! Esto es lo que estaba intentando encontrar y solucionar. 
Se que usando Try como en la respuesta de abajo lo iba a poder solucionar. Pero tenia que resolverlo sin el try y except, por eso necesitaba algo asi, mas simple pero no encontraba la solucion. 
MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS. DE VERDAD.